# Xcode puts C VLAs on the stack and not on the heap

Tags: arrays, c, xcode

Xcode puts C variable-length arrays on the stack and not on the heap.

Is this correct? If yes, considering VLAs should let developer avoid malloc-free calls, why Xcode does it?

Comment: That is normal. A fixed length automatic array will go on the stack too, not the heap.

Comment: XCode isn't a compiler, it's an IDE.  Your question is about whichever compiler it is using underneath.  But yes, every compiler I know uses the stack for VLAs.  Using the heap has various problems: it is harder to arrange for automatic freeing, and it won't work on "bare metal" environments that don't have dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @NateEldredge weren't VLAs added to the standard exactly to avoid malloc and free operations (prone to errors)? Is so VLA a "failed feature"?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean.  VLAs were introduced as a standard-blessed version of the `alloca` stack allocation feature which many implementations already provided.  If it just used the same mechanisms as `malloc` and `free` underneath then it would need some sort of "destructor" mechanism to allow for freeing, and that was never the intention.  There are certainly many who feel it was a bad idea (you never know what the maximum size is, and failure causes an unrecoverable crash) but I'm not sure what you mean by "failed feature".

Comment: VLAs *do* avoid malloc and free operations: the programmer doesn't have to call malloc/free explicitly to use them, and the implementation doesn't have to call them internally either.  I am not sure why you seem to be saying that malloc/free are not avoided.

Comment: @NateEldredge because I've seen a video by Dan Saks, in which he explains you can avoid to call malloc and free, and still have you array allocated on the heap, by using VLAs. Maybe I got it wrong, it talks about modern features in C. https://youtu.be/ieERUEhs910?t=2972

Comment: Saks does not get specific about the mechanics.  At 50:58, Saks says "I didn't look carefully at very many implementations but these are probably not on the stack, these are probably managed dynamic... the implementation is not specified as to where that storage comes from, it's a matter of the runtime system deciding whether it will use heap or... you can often do this stuff with stack allocation." He probably should have looked carefully because in practice, all common implementations I know of do use stack.

Comment: He says it *could* use heap, not that it *does*, and in principle it *could*.  But such an implementation would be so complex that I'm not aware of any widely used compiler that actually *does* use the heap.  (Here I speak of compilers that target real CPUs, not VMs or interpreted implementations.)

Comment: thanks, this explains all. I'll mark Eric'answer as accepted because you supported it in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the stack is the natural way to implement variable-length arrays and any other object with automatic storage duration because:

- The stack is designed for last-in-first-out memory use: The data for a function (or a nested block) is pushed onto the stack when the function starts, and it is removed from the stack when execution of the function ends.
- Allocation and release are easy. Each is achieved just by adjusting the stack pointer, and it can be easily adjusted by the size needed for a variable-length array.

Implementing them with allocation from the same pool used for `malloc` would be a problem because a function is not always terminated by returning. C has `setjmp` and `longjmp` features that allow jumping directly to an earlier point in the call stack. `longjmp` can be implemented mostly by setting the stack pointer and program counter to the values they had when the `setjmp` was performed, and those values are stored in the `setjmp` context object. If variable-length arrays were allocated from the `malloc` pool, it would be necessary to go through all the levels of the call tree on the stack, find the variable-length arrays that were allocated in each, and free them. And that means it would also be necessary to create records of those allocations in the stack tree as they are made.

Comment: Yep.  In short, it means recreating C++'s `throw/catch` exception mechanism, where all destructors get called.  And I think it's pretty clear the C standard committee never intended to impose that on all C implementations.